# How to keep table in the chapter title page

Tags: tables

In my thesis I have two chapters at the beginning, list of abbreviations and list of symbols, that consist only of a table. Unfortunately while converting to pdf LyX puts the tables on the next page, while I would like them to start immediately under the title chapter. Is there a way to stop LyX from putting tables on a clear page after chapter title?

Working example:

```
\chapter*{List of abbreviations}

\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}

\ra{1.3}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}\midrule
Abbreviation & Meaning \\
\midrule

AFM & atomic force microscopy\\
CM & crosslinking monomer\\

\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\chapter*{List of symbols}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}\midrule
Symbol & Meaning \\
\midrule

CPE & Constant phase element \\
W & Warburg impedance\\

\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\chapter*{}
\end{document}
```

and lines from the document that might provide you with some information:

```
\documentclass[oneside,american,english]{book}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{subscript}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\DeclareRobustCommand{\greektext}{%
  \fontencoding{LGR}\selectfont\def\encodingdefault{LGR}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\textgreek}[1]{\leavevmode{\greektext #1}}
\DeclareFontEncoding{LGR}{}{}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\~}{LGR}{126}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{booktabs} 

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{american}%
```

Comment: This is not a MWE at all! As long as your table is floating, it will go basically to anywhere ;-)

Comment: use [h] when you use \begin{table}[h] command. Contents will display immediately after the list of abbreviations and List of symbols

Comment: I've shortened the example to look more like MWE. and adding [h] works perfectly, I feel kind of stupid for not using it in the first place since it's really the basics... Thank you for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
\begin{table}[!htb]
```

then the tabular will appear in *most*, but not all cases, at the defined position.

Comment: adding [h] works perfectly, I feel kind of stupid for not using it in the first place since it's really the basics... Thank you for help

Comment: Use the exclamation mark, too.